# Volume of the solid bounded by $4x^2 + y^2 =4$ , $z=o$ and $z=x+5$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

I need to find the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinder $4x^2 + y^2 =4$ ,  $z=o$ and the plane $z=x+5$. I know that $0 \le z \le x+5$ , $-2 \sqrt{1-x^2} \le y\le 2 \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-1 \le x\le 1$. This gives me $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-2 \sqrt{1-x^2}} ^{2 \sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_0 ^{x+5} dzdydx$.

I'm stuck here. I think I need to use cylindrical coordinates but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: First you have dx twice.

Answer (score 0):

The first integral gives you, $(x+5)$.

The second gives you, $y(x+5)|_{y=-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y=2\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 4\sqrt{1-x^2}(x+5)$.

Now just take the integral of this with respect to $x$, remembering that $z$ is to be considered a constant.

Solve: $4 \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}(x+5) dx$. Use $u=1-x^2$

Let me know if this doesn't work out for you :).

Comment: I solved the problem using "elliptical" coordinates. I had trouble using that substitution. However, I'm curious and I would be thankful if you told me how to use that substitution (I end up with two square roots and I can't solve it...). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay that may have been a bad way to go, but you can separate the integrals and have 4[$\int_{-1}^{1} x\sqrt{1-x^2} dx + 5\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$ dx] on the latter this is just the arc of a semi circle of radius 1 and you can use area of a semi circle and multiply that by 5. for the first one now take u=1-x^2 then du=-2x dx and divide by -2 and you can do a replacement that way.

Comment: Oh, or I could use trigonometric substitution.

Comment: @mandlao: Also if this helped you, would you mind checking it.:) Glad to help